# Anyway to change color/font for certain parts of a ExpandableListView child text?

Tags: android, fonts, colors, expandablelistview

I want to change only certain parts of my child text(in my ExpandableListview) to different colour’s and or fonts.

Example:

Hello, World!  (I want Hello only in bold)

If this is possible, someone please share it.

ExpandableListadapter:

```
public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Group> groups;

    public ExpandListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Group> groups) {
        this.context = context;
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        ArrayList<Child> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
        return chList.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Child child = (Child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        tv.setText(child.getName().toString());
        iv.setImageResource(child.getImage());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        ArrayList<Child> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
        return chList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Group group = (Group) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_name);
        tv.setText(group.getName());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled on creating a setter and getter for a bold textview that I then hooked to an array list for a Expandablelistview.  It might not be the most efficient way but it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any sane way of doing this without breaking the text into separate TextViews.

You can split the incoming string `child.getName().toString().split(",")` (see [Split documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm)) and use the resulting array to populate separate TextViews with each having different styles.

For example in your existing `getChildView`:

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country_name_1);
TextView tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country_name_2);
String[] splitString = child.getName().toString().split(",");
tv1.setText(splitString[0]);
tv2.setText(splitString[1]);
```

You're going to have add in some error checking of course but that will be up to you (make sure child.getName() isn't null, splitString is at least of length 2 so you don't get an index out bounds exception, etc.).

Comment: And I would put this in my adapter or where my information is?

Comment: In your adapter where you're already setting the text
        `TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        tv.setText(child.getName().toString());
        iv.setImageResource(child.getImage());`

Comment: Could you show me an example? I'm kind of a beginner with this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Does the String go in the .split(",");? How does it split it?

Comment: See [documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm). If your string looks like `String s = "Hello, World"` then you'd do: `String[] sArray = s.split(",");` which splits the string where it finds a "," so you end up with `s[0] == "Hello"` and `s[1] == "World"`. If instead of a "," there was just a space, " ", then you'd do `s.split(" ");`.

Again, read the documentation and see what else you can do with java strings.